# Array printed correctly in controller,but not printed in the view page

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

`print_r($listb)` is working correctly in controller. but when we are passing this array to view page, its not working in the view page. Controller and view page and Model function is given below:

**Controller**

```
 public function index() {
                $this->load->helper('url');
                $this->load->view('user/templates/header');
                $data['banner'] = $this->banner_model->viewbanner();
                $this->load->view('user/templates/sidebar', $data);
                $data1['list1'] = $this->featured_model->viewfeaturedlist(1);
                $listb = array();
                foreach ($data1['list1'] as $list1) {
                    $list = explode(',', $list1->fet_list);
                    $type = $list1->fet_type;

                    foreach ($list as $pid) {
                        if ($type == 1) {

                            $listb['hhh'] = $this->featured_model->viewb2bproduct($pid);
                            //print_r($listb);
                        }
                    }
                }

                $this->load->view('user/templates/featured', $listb);


                exit;
                $this->load->view('user/templates/footer');
            }

        }`enter code here`
```

**View**

```
<?php
print_r($hhh);
?>
```

**Model**

```
 public function viewb2bproduct($id) {
         $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('jil_products');
        $this->db->where('prd_id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: what is the error message printed in the view ??

Comment: view page will be blank. array is not printing

Comment: Do you have Error reporting enabled ??

Comment: go to root directory and open index.php you can see define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production'); change it to  define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');  this way you can see the error report

Comment: i had an array of product ids,that is $list array. i have to fetch all details of these product id from product table and have to display in the view page. for that i wrote this code. when print_r($listb) and exit in the cotroller all the datas are getting. but when pass it to view page, nothing wil be printed

Comment: but in your view page you print $hhh ?

Comment: $listb['hhh'] is printed as $hhh in codeigniter.

Comment: ok sorry. have you enable the error report ?

Comment: in codeigniter array printing like so $data1['list1']  in controller wil be printed as $list1 in view page

Comment: yes enabled error report

Comment: In the `index.php` file in your project root change the line `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');` to this  `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');`

Comment: what is the error message ? or still blank page ?

Comment: yes still blank it is

Comment: Above the `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');` Add these two lines : `ini_set('display_errors','On'); ` and `error_reporting(E_ALL); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller Change this Line :

```
$listb['hhh'] = $this->featured_model->viewb2bproduct($pid);
```

to

```
$listb['hhh'][] = $this->featured_model->viewb2bproduct($pid);
```

In view :

```
<?php 

foreach ($fff as $product){

  echo $products[0]['prd_id']."<br>"; 
  echo $products[0]['prd_name']."<br>";  //and so on
}
```

Comment: You view page will have the same code as you have right now : `<?php print_r($hhh); ?>`

Comment: Always happy to help :)

Comment: Thanks again for your helping mentality :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `$listb['hhh']` is in foreach loop and you are overriding it each time for every element of `$list`. and in controller you are printing it inside the `foreach` loop thats why it is giving output but not in your `view`.

Comment: foreach($hhh as $products)
                                  {
                                     echo $products[0]['prd_id'].'<br>';
                                      echo $products[0]['prd_name'].'<br>';
                                  } i got the result using this code. but is a good solution?

Comment: foreach($hhh as $key => $products)
            {
              echo $products['prd_id'];
            }

It may be!

Comment: Vinie Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

**In model**

```
public function viewb2bproduct($id) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('jil_products');
    $this->db->where('prd_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;     
}
```

**In controller**

```
public function index() 
{
        $this->load->helper('url');

        $data['banner'] = $this->banner_model->viewbanner();

        $data1['list1'] = $this->featured_model->viewfeaturedlist(1); 

        $this->load->view('user/templates/sidebar', $data);
        $this->load->view('user/templates/header');
        $this->load->view('user/templates/featured', $listb);
        $this->load->view('user/templates/footer');
    }

}
```

and **in view**

```
<?php
    foreach ($list1 as $new_list1) 
    {
        echo "<p>".$new_list1['table_field']."</p>"
    }
```

I **have no idea on this part**

```
   $listb = array();
    foreach ($data1['list1'] as $list1) 
    {
        $list = explode(',', $list1->fet_list);
        $type = $list1->fet_type;

        foreach ($list as $pid) {
            if ($type == 1) {

                $listb['hhh'] = $this->featured_model->viewb2bproduct($pid);
                //print_r($listb);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me

Comment: Happy to hear this  from you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
      $hhh=array();

      foreach ($data1['list1'] as $list1) {
                $list = explode(',', $list1->fet_list);
                $type = $list1->fet_type;

                foreach ($list as $pid) {
                    if ($type == 1) {

                        $hhh[] = $this->featured_model->viewb2bproduct($pid);
                        //print_r($listb);
                    }
                }
            }
        $listb['hhh']=$hhh;
       $this->load->view('user/templates/featured', $listb);
```

Comment: Thanks Nikunj Chavda :)

Comment: It my pleasure Angel :)

Comment: Happy to hear this :)